# Estimate the value of f at a given point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable everywhere. Assume $f(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)=0$, and also that 
$|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)|\le |\sin(x^2+y^2)|$ and $|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)|\le |\cos(x^2+y^2)|$ for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} $. Prove that $|f(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)|\le 4$. I tried to use the Taylor expansion at the point $(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)$ as follows,

$f(x,y)=f(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)+ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)(y+\sqrt2)+ \epsilon(||(x+\sqrt2,y+\sqrt2)||) $

$=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)(y+\sqrt2)+ \epsilon(||(x+\sqrt2,y+\sqrt2)||).$

Using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, we obtain the upper bound of $ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)(y+\sqrt2)$ at the point $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt2)$ is 4. However, I don't know how to deal with the $\epsilon(||(x+\sqrt2,y+\sqrt2)||) $. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\le t \le 1,$ let

$$g(t) = f((-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2) + t(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)).$$

Then $g$ is differentiable on $[0,1].$ Note that $g(1)-g(0) = f(0,0) - f(-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2).$ By the mean value theorem,

$$g(1) - g(0) = g'(c)\cdot 1 = \nabla f ((-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2) + c(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)) \cdot (\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2))$$

for some $c\in (0,1).$ Now $|\nabla f | \le 1 $ away from $(0,0),$ so Cauchy-Schwartz applied to the above gives $|g(1) - g(0)| \le 1\cdot 2 = 2.$

The same argument applies to $f(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)-f(0,0).$ Put this together with the above and use $f((-\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2))=0$ to get the result.

Comment: thank you very much for providing another way to solve. Could you please help me to modify my solution using Taylor expansion?